# How to print all permutations of a number

Tags: c++, algorithm

Can anyone help me with a C++ code that prints out all the possible permutations of the given number.

For example, if the number N = 123, then {123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321} are the possible permutations.

I have researched and could find the code only for string and not an integer.

Thanks.

Comment: convert int to string first and re-use code you've found

Comment: It's no different.

Comment: You don't have to convert string to integer. Make 'N' as string will be enough

Comment: I need to use the permutations for further calculations, so i guess I will have to convert them into integers again?

Answer (score 4):

You might use:

```
void display_permutation(std::size_t n)
{
    std::string s = std::to_string(n);
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    do {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    } while (std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/D3nt1y)

Comment: Thanks. But I could not get your point. Can you please elaborate your code?

Comment: Which parts is unclear for you ? Have you look to documentation of [std::to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and especially of [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) ?

Comment: Got it now. Thanks!